# What's a suitable way of combining how and why questions?

Tags: questions

How can I combine these two sentences?
A) Why do you want to go to California?
B) How will you go to California?

Saying "Why and how will you go to California?" is wrong but then how should I combine them?

Comment: Why do you believe that "Why and how will you go to California?" is wrong?

Comment: It's pretty peremptory, like an investigation. The easiest way to combine questions is just to ask them in a row. _Why do you want to go to California? And how are you planning to get there?_

Comment: It is a matter of style and emphasis.  Do you want to be as brief as possible?  KillingTime's suggestion will fit the job.  But the "why" sounds like a challenge, hinting that this is not the time or California is not the place.  You could say "why are you going to California and how will you get there?"  But neither of these is a matter of grammar.

Comment: Why do you want to go to California, and how would you get there?

Comment: "How and why" sounds more natural than "why and how", but Google shows both are in use. Try searching for the phrases "how and why will" and "why and how will", and see what you find.

Comment: It also depends on the context.  In normal use it would be unusual to combine them into one question like that without a good reason for it (e.g. humor: How will you be getting to California and *why* would you want to?).

Answer (score 1):

> How and why are you going to California?

is pretty clear and acceptable. It erases the difference between "Why you are going" and "Why you want to go", but that difference is usually negligible and often non-existent.

Alternatively:

> How are you going to California and why do you want to?

works, or

> Why do you want to go to California and how are you going?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I really learnt new way of combining sentences. Killing time, you were right. My suppositions was wrong.Thanks a lot.